# Getting the MSI Certificate rather than the MSIEXEC certificate

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a MSI in which I have created a custom action to elevate the privileges whenever the MSI starts. The MSI is signed, however, when I run it through the custom installer it shows the certificate of Windows Installer. Is there a way with which I can get the MSI certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... This is how I have resolved this... Rather than directly calling the msiexec... I am calling it through an exe wrapper... The exe wrapper is called through the custom action... I have also signed the exe wrapper so I see the correct certificate...